# How to select split string from column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to select split records from the phone column.

My table looks like that:

```
customerId      phone                       address      ...
 1              1234567                     qwe          ...
 2              234567,135791,4556457       asd          ...
 3              3425546,34454365            zxc          ...
```

I need to select each phone number separately with the customerId:

```
1  1234567
2  234567
2  135791
2  4556457
3  3425546
3  34454365
```

I don't want to change table and split to different rows, only to select.

Thanks!

Comment: Comma separated items... always causing problems.

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` - look it up, should get you what you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string) particularly this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `string_split()` in concert with a `CROSS APPLY`... Use `OUTER APPLY` if you want to see NULL values

```
Select A.customerID
      ,Phone = B.value
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply string_split(A.Phone,',') B
```

Comment: sorry for the delay, it works great!!

Comment: i didnt know, done. Thanks!